# Add users/groups to team project groups with Powershell in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a powershell script to create team projects, git repos, branches, pushes etc.
I use the Rest API and tf.exe with OAuth authentification.

How can I add DevOps users/groups from the organization level to DevOps groups on project level with powershell?
I want to add a "global" group to Contributors, for example.

Can it be done with the security rest api ([docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-identity?view=vsts))?
I can't find any examples on how to work with that api.

Or can it be done with [tfssecurity.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd)? How can I use Oauth with tfssecurity?

thanks
Tobias